# WordPress CPT causing 404s when categories are added to permalinks

Tags: php, wordpress, http-status-code-404, permalinks

I created a custom post type (CPT) and taxonomies for a gallery that is working fine.

The problem is with the permalinks for non-CPT posts which go to 404s when I add /%category%/ to the permalink structure.

The permalinks work when (1) I remove the custom taxonomy from functions.php, or (2) when I remove /%category%/ from permalinks. Therefore I know the problem is with the CPT or/and taxonomy code in the functions.php but I can not see the problem.  Your help is greatly appreciated.

```
/* Custom Post Type - Gallery */
add_action( 'init', 'add_gallery_post_type' );
function add_gallery_post_type() {
    register_post_type(
        'zm_gallery',
        array(
            'labels'             => array(
                'name'          => __( 'The Gallery' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'The Gallery' ),
                'add_new_item'  => __( 'Add New Photograph' ),
                'all_items'     => __( 'All Images' ),
            ),
            'public'             => true,
            'has_archive'        => true,
            'rewrite'            => array( 'slug' => 'gallery-item' ),
            'supports'           => array( 'title' ),
            'menu_position'      => 4,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'show_ui'            => true,
            'show_in_menu'       => true,
            'query_var'          => true,
            'menu_icon'          => 'dashicons-camera',
            'capability_type'    => 'post',

        )
    );
}


/* Gallery Taxonomies */

function be_register_taxonomies() {

    $taxonomies = array(
        array(
            'slug'        => 'location',
            'single_name' => 'Location',
            'plural_name' => 'Locations',
            'post_type'   => 'zm_gallery',
        ),
        array(
            'slug'        => 'circa',
            'single_name' => 'Circa',
            'plural_name' => 'Circas',
            'post_type'   => 'zm_gallery',
        ),
        array(
            'slug'        => 'era',
            'single_name' => 'Era',
            'plural_name' => 'Era',
            'post_type'   => 'zm_gallery',
        ),
    );

    foreach ( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {
        $labels = array(
            'name'              => $taxonomy['plural_name'],
            'singular_name'     => $taxonomy['single_name'],
            'search_items'      => 'Search ' . $taxonomy['plural_name'],
            'all_items'         => 'All ' . $taxonomy['plural_name'],
            'parent_item'       => 'Parent ' . $taxonomy['single_name'],
            'parent_item_colon' => 'Parent ' . $taxonomy['single_name'] . ':',
            'edit_item'         => 'Edit ' . $taxonomy['single_name'],
            'update_item'       => 'Update ' . $taxonomy['single_name'],
            'add_new_item'      => 'Add New ' . $taxonomy['single_name'],
            'new_item_name'     => 'New ' . $taxonomy['single_name'] . ' Name',
            'menu_name'         => $taxonomy['plural_name'],
        );

        $rewrite      = isset( $taxonomy['rewrite'] ) ? $taxonomy['rewrite'] : array( 'slug' => $taxonomy['slug'] );
        $hierarchical = isset( $taxonomy['hierarchical'] ) ? $taxonomy['hierarchical'] : true;

        register_taxonomy(
            $taxonomy['slug'],
            $taxonomy['post_type'],
            array(
                'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
                'labels'       => $labels,
                'show_ui'      => true,
                'query_var'    => true,
                'rewrite'      => $rewrite,
            )
        );
    }

}

add_action( 'init', 'be_register_taxonomies' );
```

Comment: I tested your code, and I don't see a problem. Have you saved permalinks after adding the Custom Post Type?

Comment: In order to test I try something or turn something off, etc., then I change permalinks to plain and then back to custom /%category%/%postname%/ and then try again.  If I don't put the /%category%/ in the permalink it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Okay.  My bad.  The problem was that the main default category for posts was set to "General".  When I created the CPT I also created a category called "General".  WordPress was getting confused.  I renamed the main post category to "News" and now everything works fine.